# laravel 5.2 greggilbert/recaptcha : Please ensure that you are a human

Tags: laravel, recaptcha

I used greggilbert/recaptcha in my laravel 5.2 project. Though the form data are valid, after submit the form I always get the error message: Please ensure that you are a human!

I tried a lot but do not find any solution. Do you anybody  help me? pls.

I used these codes:

In the Form:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                {!! Recaptcha::render() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
```

To get Error Message,

```
@section('message')
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <h3>Message Sending Failed!</h3>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@else
    <h3>
        @if(isset($heading))
            {{$heading}}
        @endif
    </h3>
    <p>
        @if(isset($body))
            {{$body}}
        @endif
    </p>
@endif

@endsection
```

In the Controller:

```
public function save(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'Name' => 'required|max:40',
        'Email' => 'email|required',
        'Heading' => 'required|max:200',
        'Message' => 'required|max:1000',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha',
    ]);

    $contact = new Contact();

    $contact->name = $request->Name;
    $contact->email = $request->Email;
    $contact->heading = $request->Heading;
    $contact->message = $request->Message;

    $contact->save();

    $msg['heading'] = 'Thank You! for contacting us.';
    $msg['body'] = 'We will try to Answer to your Query as soon as possible.';

    return redirect('/contact')->with($msg);

}
```

In the config/recaptcha.php

```
'public_key'     => env('RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY', '6LfjMiETAA_Rest of the key Hidden'),
'private_key'    => env('RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY', '6LfjMi_Rest of the key Hidden'),
```

Comment: @Karl
I added some code above.

Answer (score 4):

Problem Solved:

After changing 
    'curl_timeout' => 1,
to
'curl_timeout' => 10,
at config/recaptcha.php

Answer (score 0):

Please change config/recaptcha.php

Set the following options at recaptcha.php file

```
'options'     => [

    'curl_timeout' => 10,
    'curl_verify' => false,

],
```